# Restore database in mysql command line

Tags: mysql

I have taken a backup of a database from one server and trying to restore it in another server.

Mysql version is 5.5

When I try to restore the database using the following command, screen -r

```
mysql -u root -p password mydb < mydump.sql
ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line 356: Can't create table 'mydb.mytable' (errno: 150)
```

I understand this is foreignkey constraint problem.  The dump file has the following statement inside.

```
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
```

But it is still failing.  My dumo file is very large is size, so opening it and editing is not possible.  So instead of adding `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` in the dump, can I directly set it inside the mysql commandline like the following?

```
mysql> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
...
mysql> source "mydump.sql";
...
mysql> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Will it work?  My database reload takes hours to complete.  So I am asking the help here before spending hours on this.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, I'll just pipe in 2 sql files -- first, a one-liner with `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;`, and then dump file.  You needn't worry about setting it back; it will only last for the current session (which will terminate when the files have been loaded).

FYI, you can also use `sed -i 1i"SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;" dump.sql` if you want to permanently prepend this line without visually editing the file.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet.  But it kind of helps to proceed.  Thanks